# Is there a Wikidata - based Entity system yet?

Tags: packages, curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries, entity

Wikidata.org seems to have a similar goal as the new Entity/EntityProperty Wolfram-knowledge base system.

The differences are that Wikidata is open, promising faster expansion and fixing, but of course maybe more errors than the Wolfram closed system curated data. The tradeoff is similar to what we have with primary sources versus Wikipedia article. Still it has high brow support, a million of funding from e.g. Google who abandoned their Freebase project in favor of it so we shouldnt miss out.

Anyhow, is there any "WikidataEntity[]" library yet or will we have to pull this off some time soon?

**Aside**

WikipediaData already indirectly uses some of Wikidata.org, namely via LanguagesList and LanguagesURLs as these are stored in Wikidata since 2013.

However according to WRI it is not directly queried:

> Are you actually using Wikidata? http://wikidata.org/
>
> > Thank you for your comment, at this time our WikipediaData does not
> >     pull from wikidata.org. Posted by The Wolfram Team    April 13, 2015
> >     at 10:17 am

http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/03/20/new-in-the-wolfram-language-wikipediadata/